# Copy/Stream file from Machine B to Machine C that is started from Machine A

Tags: c#

I'm trying to copy a file from Machine B to Machine C that is started from Machine A but I don't want the file to go through Machine A. Using the built in `File.Copy` method, the data goes through Machine A and then to Machine C instead of straight to Machine C, doubling the network traffic. Is there any way around this?

The best option I know of right now is to remotely start a robocopy on Machine B that copies the file to Machine C and then watch for the end of the process. I was hoping that there would be a cleaner way of doing it that is all in C#.

Comment: "_Is there any way around this?_" Perhaps. Set up your network and your shared network folders in such a way that allows copying a file directly from B to C. How to do this exactly and in detail, you ask? How should i know what precise (network configuration) tasks/steps you will have to undertake? I don't know the circumstances and the network environment in which you operate and what possible constraints/limitations with regard to possibly feasible network setups you are facing...

Comment: (Note that questions regarding configuration of a network environment would usually be off-topic for SO, because such would not be a coding/programming-related question. http://superuser.com would be a better place for asking about things related to network configuration.)

Comment: You're on the right track with the Robocopy thing - the only way to do it is to instruct Machine B to copy to Machine C.  Maybe write a proxy application that sits on one of the machines (your own version of Robocopy)??